# Airplane Mode in Apple Watch without cellular

Tags: apple-watch, airplane-mode

What's the point of Airplane Mode in Apple Watch models that have no cellular capabilities?

I believe it will not turn off Bluetooth (as it will disconnect the Watch from iPhone), and then we left only with Wifi. Is it only for Wifi? Because Wifi has it's own toggling button

Comment: idk specifically for the watch, but airplane mode is supposed to switch off **all** radios - that's the entire point.

Comment: Exactly. Apple Watch has GPS+GLONASS for example and the U1 chip as well. Not sure if they are all switched off but for sure some.

Comment: Who knows? I'm not sure GPS is turned off